# How to draw an histogram with float values and a specific step?

Tags: plot, rust, data-science, visualization

I am trying stuff out with plotter-rs and I wanted to create an histogram with float values ranging from 0.0f64 to 1.0f64 and have like 50 segments.

Following is what I have been trying. `.build_cartesion_2d()` is the part that creates bars with a define range on the x and y axis.

```
use plotters::prelude::*;
use tch::{kind,Tensor};

let path = path.unwrap_or("plots/0.png");
let root = BitMapBackend::new(path, (1280, 720)).into_drawing_area();
root.fill(&WHITE)?;
let mut chart = ChartBuilder::on(&root)
    .set_label_area_size(LabelAreaPosition::Left, 40)
    .set_label_area_size(LabelAreaPosition::Bottom, 40)
    .caption("Histogram", ("sans-serif", 40))
    .build_cartesian_2d((0i64..10).into_segmented(), 0i64..100)
    .unwrap();

chart.configure_mesh().draw().unwrap();
let t = Tensor::rand(&[100], kind::FLOAT_CPU);
t.print();
let data: ndarray::ArrayD<f64> = (&t).try_into().unwrap();

root.draw_series(
     Histogram::vertical(&chart)
     .style(BLUE.filled())
     .margin(10)
     .data(data.map(|x| (((x*100.).round()/100.) as i64, 1))),
).unwrap();
```

Cargo.toml :

````
[package]
name = "test-rs"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.15.6"
plotters = "0.3.4"
tch = "0.10.1"```
````